# Define Bytes in AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am new to AT&T syntax (I used to code for NASM) and can't seem to find the equivalent of Intel's DB (Define Byte)
I am trying to OSDev and need to define:
`db 0x55`
`db 0xAA`

Comment: Please refer to the GNU as manual for the directives available.

Comment: assembly language is specific to the tool not the target. AT&T is a convention and does not cover the details nor differences of the various languages for x86.

Comment: @old_timer: In practice there's only one widely-used overall syntax that uses AT&T for instructions, so Unix / GAS directives "go with" AT&T syntax strongly enough that the [att] tag isn't truly wrong for this question.  I'm not going to add it back in, but I wouldn't have removed it.  I'd expect many novices to search on [att] while looking for a question like this.  (I should have removed [bare-metal] when I added [gnu-assembler] though.)  Of course there aren't that many GAS directives in the manual, and it's easy to look at gcc output for global `char foo = 123;`.

Comment: nothing about the question was related to at&t vs intel. if there had been then it would be a valid tag.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it seems it is replaced with .byte